# I can't post a question, with similar name as another one..?

Tags: support

I have a question with title:

```
 Is it worth it (when shooting) to use .. ( episode 2 ) : Noise reduction?
```

And I want to paste another one, with title:

```
Is it worth it (when shooting) to use .. ( episode 3 ): sharpness control?
```

As both were in one question(with some others), but moderators advised to separate them into different ones. But this gives me:

```
Sorry, this is a duplicate question of: 
Is it worth it (when shooting) to use .. ( episode 2 ) : Noise reduction?
```

Ant it's not true.. Why should I use completely different names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better question, is there a good reason to use such similar names?

It is best to ask each question independently, so that each one can stand alone.  That way you get the best answer for the specific question.  When you combine them (or otherwise link them by the naming) you'll have a harder time getting a clear answer because the other factors will be considered, even if they have no bearing on specific topic.

For example:

> Is it worth it (when shooting) to use .. ( episode 2 ) : Noise
>   reduction?

could be better written as:

> Is it advisable to use in camera noise reduction?

Comment: Yes, this was the solution. But my idea was to make them as questions from one type, and to be something like "episodes". Anyway, renaming the question fixed the problem. I was just surprised from this behavior.

Comment: @Kiril I understand that you might want to link the questions, but that could actually make it harder for someone to find the answer, if they have the same question.

Comment: @Rowland - yes, you're actually right. Thannks

Comment: The tagging mechanism can be used to group similar-type posts together.